# does changing the cable length of NTC temperature sensor affect accuracy?

Tags: components, cables, thermistor

I'm using an off-the-shelf STC-1000 temperature controller, popular with homebrewers, that uses an NTC sensor to read temperature and switch on a relay to cool or heat when the sensed temperature exceeds the set limit.
I needed the 2m cable of the sensor to be longer, so I extended it by 3m.

By how much could the extending the wire affect the accuracy of the sensor?

Comment: What is the resistance range of the NTC? Or what is the nominal resistance? Most likely the longer cable will have a negligible effect. The only possible issue is greater noise pick-up in the longer cable. I wouldn't expect this to be a problem, though. There is probably some noise filtering or averaging somewhere in the system, either in hardware or software.

Comment: I once did this calculation for a 10kOhm NTC and cables of about 50m. The effect was less than 0.2°C, but of course it depends on the wire gauge. What is the highest temperature you are going to measure? What's the resistance there? Add the resistance of the cable and calculate the temperature. The difference is the worst case error.

Answer (score 4):

By taking the resistance of the wire you will add, along with the resistance range of the NTC sensor, you can adjust for any accuracy issues. Simply subtract the wire's resistance (voltage drop over it) from the NTC Sensor's reading.